# Dynamic order by in SqlDataSource by a dropdownlist and grid view

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I have a grid view that connect to the DataSqlSource. I want to sort my queries dynamically by a dropdownlist. for example by date,name,family etc.
I also join some tables in my queries.
I use this code in my DataSqlSource:

```
  SELECT AddTitle.Title, SubmitManuscript.Status, AddArticleType.Type, AddArticleType.UserName, AddArticleType.ArticleType, SubmitManuscript.date, SubmitManuscript.ArticleNum, AddArticleType.ArticleID, CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), SubmitManuscript.date, 103) AS date1, OtherWritter.ArticleID AS Expr1, OtherWritter.name, OtherWritter.family, AddArticleType.CheckFinish FROM AddArticleType INNER JOIN AddTitle ON AddArticleType.ArticleID = AddTitle.ArticleID INNER JOIN SubmitManuscript ON AddArticleType.ArticleID = SubmitManuscript.ArticleID INNER JOIN OtherWritter ON AddTitle.ArticleID = OtherWritter.ArticleID WHERE (AddArticleType.ArticleID IN (SELECT ArticleID FROM AddUpload_4 AS AddUpload_4_1 WHERE (AddArticleType.CheckFinish = '0'))) AND (AddArticleType.Type = @Type) AND (SubmitManuscript.Status = 'Accept') AND 
(OtherWritter.MainAuthor = 'Yes') ORDER BY '[' + @SortOrder + ']' DESC
```

but it doesn't work for me and no sorting happen!

And I also try this code, this time it gave me an error:
here is the code:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @order=Country THEN Country  END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @order= City THEN City  END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @order= name THEN name  END ASC
```

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @order='Country' THEN Country  END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @order='City' THEN City  END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @order='name' THEN name  END ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying but, it gave me this error:
The CLR type does not exist or you do not have permissions to access it...:((